# Container for double and a pointer C++?

Tags: c++, pointers, containers

I have two questions.
1. Am I using the most effective container for holding a [double, object*]?
2. If Map is the choice I should use, how in the world do I access the object being pointed too once it's in the map? I am trying to print the map in function printMap() without any luck. Tried multiple variations.

```
  void printMap() {  //How do i verify what's in my map??!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
            for (it = cDatabase.begin(); it != cDatabase.end(); it++)
            {
                double temp = 0;
                temp = it->first;
                cout << "Key: " << it->first << endl;
                cout << cDatabase[it->first]->getFirstName();
            }
        }
```

Thanks in advance

Erik

PS: I included the entire .cpp file.

```cpp
//Erik Plachta
//Purpose: Creating a Customer Relations Management system. Should be able to create employees and customers that can we stored within a database.

#include<fstream>      //for customer database
#include<map>          //for customer database
#include<sstream>       //for customer database
#include<stdlib.h>        //for customer database

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
/////EMPLOYEE///////////EMPLOYEE////////////EMPLOYEE/////////EMPLOYEE//////////
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
class Employee {

    string firstName, lastName, password, username;  //used to create unique sessions for each user. Login info
    bool manager;   //If manager, will have spec privlages within the app.
    int sessionTime; //used to record login/logoff time. 

    public:
        Employee(string FN, string LN, string pass, string userN) { //first name, last name and pass
           setName(FN, LN);
           setPassword(pass); 
           setUsername(userN);
        }

        string getName() {
            string fullName = firstName + " " + lastName;
            return fullName;
        }

        bool confirmPassword(string pass) {  //used to test if true or false without giving program the password back.
            bool status = false; 
            if (pass == password) {
                status = true;
            } 
            return status;
        }

        bool confirmUsername(string userN) {
            bool status = false;
            if (userN == username) {
                status = true;
            }
            return status;
        }

    private:
        void setName(string FN, string LN) {
            firstName = FN;
            lastName = LN;}

        void setPassword (string pass) {
            password = pass;
        }

        void setUsername(string userN) {
            username = userN;
        }
};


void printEmployee(Employee employee) {  //this is confirming the password entered was the same in the database. there will be a private database holding user login info
    bool status;
    cout <<"Name: " << employee.getName() << endl;
    status = employee.confirmPassword("123456"); 
    cout << "Password test: " << status << endl;
    status = employee.confirmUsername("EPlachta");
    cout << "Username test: " << status << endl;
}

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
///CUSTOMER////////////CUSTOMER/////////CUSTOMER/////CUSTOMER//////CUSTOMER////
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
class Customer {
    string firstName, lastName, phoneNumber, eMail; 
    double customerNumber;
    public: 
        Customer (string FN, string LN, string phoneN, string EM, double customerNum) {
            setName(FN, LN);   
            setPhoneNumber(phoneN);
            setEmail(EM);
            setCustomerNumber(customerNum);
        }

        string getFirstName() {
            return firstName;
        }

        string getLastName() {
            return lastName;
        }

        string getPhoneNumber() {
            return phoneNumber;
        }

        string getEmailAddress(){
            return eMail;
        }

        double getCustomerNumber() {
            return customerNumber;
        }

        void printCustomer() {
            cout << "First Name: " << getFirstName() << endl;
            cout << "lastName: " << getLastName() << endl;
            cout << "Email: " << getEmailAddress() << endl;
            cout << "PhoneNumber: " << getPhoneNumber() << endl;
            cout <<"CustomerNumber: "<< getCustomerNumber() << endl;
        }

    private: 
        void setName(string FN, string LN) {
            firstName = FN;
            lastName = LN;
        }   

        void setPhoneNumber(string phoneN) {
            phoneNumber = phoneN;
        }

        void setEmail(string EM) {
            eMail = EM;
        }

        void setCustomerNumber(double customerNum) {
            customerNumber = customerNum;
        }
} ;

//print customer is uptop here for now. Will be put into it's own class


///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
///CUSTOMER DATABASE///////////////CUSTOMER DATABASE///////CUSTOMER DATABASE///
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

class CustomerDatabase {
    double customerNumbers; // used to increment from 100000 - 99999. An easy way to give out new numbers and to prevent duplicates.
    map <double, Customer*> cDatabase;
    map <double, Customer*>:: iterator it;

    public:
        CustomerDatabase() { 
            customerNumbers = 100000;
            loadCustomers();
        }
        void printMap() {  //How do i verify what's in my map??!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
            for (it = cDatabase.begin(); it != cDatabase.end(); it++)
            {
                double temp = 0;
                temp = it->first;
                cout << "Key: " << it->first << endl;
                cout << cDatabase[it->first]->getFirstName();
            }
        }
        double newCustomerNumber() {   // Used to generate unique customer IDs easily. 
            double customerNumberHolder = customerNumbers;
            customerNumbers++;
            return customerNumberHolder;
        }     

        bool saveCustomer(double customerN, Customer *c) { //saves customer to database once created  **NOT WORKING YET
            addCustomer(customerN, c);
            ofstream databaseFile;  //filestream local for output
            bool saveCustomer = false;
            if (checkForCustomerNumber(customerN) != false) { // if the customer isn't in the database
                ostringstream stream; // USED TO MAKE AN INT INTO A STRING. Local stream to keep clear
                stream << c->getCustomerNumber();
                databaseFile.open ("database/databaseFile.csv", ios::app);
                string customerHolder = c->getFirstName() + "," + c->getLastName() + "," + c->getPhoneNumber() + "," + c->getEmailAddress() + ","  + stream.str()  + "\n"  ;
                databaseFile << customerHolder;
                databaseFile.close();
                saveCustomer = true;
            }
            cout << "Customer saved Status: " << saveCustomer << endl;
            return saveCustomer;
        }        

        bool addCustomer(double customerN, Customer *c) {
            bool addCustomer = false;
            cDatabase[customerN] =  c;
            return addCustomer;

        }

    private:

        bool loadCustomers() {
            string firstN, lastN, phoneN, emailA;
            double customerN;
            const int FIRSTNAME = 0;
            const int LASTNAME = 1;
            const int PHONENUMBER = 2;
            const int EMAIL = 3;
            const int CUSTOMERNUMBER = 4;
            //skipped 5 because every new line also runs through the while loop. 
            const int ADDTODATABASE = 5;
            ifstream databaseFile; //file-stream local for input
            databaseFile.open ("database/databaseFile.csv", ios::in);
            string line = "";
            int i = 0;
            double loadedCustomers = 0; //used to keep track of customer loaded.
            while( getline(databaseFile, line, ',')) {
                if (i == FIRSTNAME) {
                    firstN = line;
                    i++;
                }  else if (i == LASTNAME) {
                    lastN = line;
                    i++;
                } else if (i == PHONENUMBER) {
                    phoneN = line;
                    i++;
                } else if (i == EMAIL) {   
                    emailA = line;
                    i++;
                } else if (i == CUSTOMERNUMBER) {
                    double customerNumb = atoi(line.c_str()); 
                    customerN = customerNumb;
                    Customer c(firstN, lastN, phoneN, emailA, customerN);
                    Customer *holder;
                    holder = &c;
                    addCustomer(c.getCustomerNumber(), holder);
                    i = 0; //resetting for next line.
                }
//this is how i was saving a customer to the database. I dont' need to save when loading customers. saving code incase needed//                saveCustomer(c.getCustomerNumber(), c);     
            }
            databaseFile.close();
        }

        bool checkForCustomerNumber(double customerN) { //If ID # is within the database, it will return a true that the ID exists
            bool customerNumberMatch = false;
            if((cDatabase.find(customerN)) != (cDatabase.end())) { //if the customer number is the key for the map, it will not reach the end. therein the customer is already in the database
                customerNumberMatch = true;
                customerNumbers++;
            }
            cout << "C. Number Match Satus: " << customerNumberMatch << endl;
            return customerNumberMatch;
        }
};


///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//MAIN////////////////MAIN/////////////MAIN////////////////MAIN/////////MAIN///
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

int main() {
    //CUSTOMER DATABASE CREATION
    CustomerDatabase customerDatabase;   //creating database
    ////CUSTOMER
    Customer JT("Johnny", "Tester", "989-123-4567", "johnnyTester@gmail.com", customerDatabase.newCustomerNumber());    // used to create a test customer

    Customer Test ("This", "is", "a", "test", 100000);
    Customer TT("Timmy", "Tester", "989-989-9898", "Erik@itsaTest.com", customerDatabase.newCustomerNumber());
    //CUSTOMER DATABASE USED
    Customer *holder;
    holder = &JT;
    customerDatabase.saveCustomer(holder->getCustomerNumber(), holder);
    holder = &TT;
    customerDatabase.saveCustomer(holder->getCustomerNumber(), holder);
    holder = &Test;
    customerDatabase.saveCustomer(holder->getCustomerNumber(), holder);
    customerDatabase.printMap();
    //EMPLOYEE
    Employee EP ("Erik", "Plachta", "123456", "EPlachta");                        //creating test employee
  //  printEmployee(EP);                                                            //making sure employee can login / was created correctly.      

    cin.get();
    return 0;
}

//Customer class looks at database for an ID it wants to use,
```

Comment: You can use: `it->second->getFirstName()`. Be aware that if you try to recreate a `key` using math the imprecision of the data type will make many keys practically unreproducible through calculation. Iterating is fine as is searching for ranges (less than).

Comment: Why in the world are you using a `double` for customer numbers?

Comment: Okay. Thanks Galik. Not sure o11c.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before starting on the choice of containers, I would like to touch upon the choice of datatype for ID numbers. You are using a double, which is a floating point number, but you only require integer values, so it would be much more sensible to use an integer type.

The choice of a container depends on how you plan to access and modify the data in the container. Some key characteristics to consider are:

1. Do you need to be able to access the elements in the container in a random sequence? Ie. look up the elements by ID? Containers which are good for this are map, unordered_map, vector. Lists are bad for this, because you would have to traverse the list to find the element you want.
2. Do you need to be able to iterate through the values in some predetermined order (eg. key order)? Containers which are good for this are map, vector, various list types.
3. Do you need to be able to insert elements at any given position? Or is it enough to insert only at the end? If the former then map, unordered_map, list are good. If the latter then a vector is good.
4. What type of key is going to be used to look up values? You can look up entries in a vector by an integer number, but if you have, for example, a string, then you would need to use a map or unordered_map.
5. If the key is numeric - is the list sparse? Ie. will there be large gaps in the sequence? If yes then a vector is less attractive because there may be large amounts of wasted memory.

The characteristics for you seem to be:

1. You need to be able to look up customers by ID
2. You need to be able to iterate through the list to print out the database. I am not sure if it is a requirement to do so in order, but let's assume it is.
3. It looks as though you are adding new entries at the end of the list.
4. The keys are integer numbers
5. I am not sure if the list will be sparse. If you delete a lot of customers from the middle then there may be gaps.

If it were not for the last point, a vector might actually be a better choice than a map. Vectors are cheap and have high performance for most of the operations you will use.

Anyway, if you do decide a map is best, based on what you know of your application, then when you iterate through the map, the iterator points towards the value_type of the container, which in the case of a map is of type std::pair, where K is the key type and V is the value type. This value type stores the key and the value, which you access using the 'first' and 'second' members.

```
for (it = cDatabase.begin(); it != cDatabase.end(); it++) {
    cout << "Key: " << it->first << endl;
    cout << it->second->getFirstName() << endl;
}
```

Comment: Beautiful. Changed it to an int, used the code you sent me and it's working. Thank you Harmic.  Not sure why I chose double to be honest. Just was thinking if I had 10,000 customers I'd have to re-write the program.
Your assumptions were correct in regards to my intentions with the program. Sounds like a map is the best option for what I am doing.